# Is this function from $[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \infty$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

just a short question. So I was wondering about functions from compact sets into
$\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$.

Let's say we have a function $f : [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$,
defined by

$f(x) = -1/x$ if $x \in [-1,0)$,

$f(0) = +\infty$,

$f(x) = 1/x$ if $x \in (0,1]$.

I think this should be continuous, although somehow my brain doesn't want 
to believe that it is.

Comment: You need to define a topology on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ first. If you make it the Alexandroff one-point compactification, for instance, your function is continuous.

Comment: @1015: topology on ℝ ∪ {+∞} is **obviously** induced by the one of the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).  It is finer than one-point compactification (and isn’t a compactification, indeed).  Wee see a case where intuition of a good college student may be more helpful than erudition about certain general-topologic stuff.  BTW, a sane person would never use the symbol “‌ **+** ∞ ” for infinity of Alexandroff extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly continuous everywhere on $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$, so we need only check continuity at $x = 0$. To talk about continuity, we need a topology, but taking a lead from the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity in real analysis, we can define $f(x)$ to be continuous with value of $\infty$ at $x = a$ if for all $N > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\left|\,f(x)\right| > N$ whenever $\left|x - a\right| < \delta$. In this case, we have $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| > N$ whenever $\left|x\right| < \frac{1}{N}$, so that $f$ is indeed continuous with value $\infty$ at $x = 0$ (you would have to check that this definition of continuity agrees with your topology on $\Bbb R\cup \{\infty\}$).

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I think I just wanted to believe that $\infty$ was something special. But with the aforementioned alexandroff compactification, it seems that the function is basically the same as a function into some interval $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$.